# How to invoke SOAP web service via AFNetworking and NSUrlSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, afnetworking, nsurlsession

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial) on how to get data via web service.
And in there author used `PHP` and `REST` to access service like:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
```

And I am having trouble to use this on .NET SOAP (.asmx) [web service like this one](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx).
How I can use `NSUrlSession` and `AFNetworking` to **send/receive** data **to/from asmx** web service?

I have a problem as I don't know how to form a request to some method on this web service and pass parameters. It's a lot different compared to SOAP. It can be that I am stupid but can't figure this alone :(

Comment: With NSUrl session no

Comment: So how do you manage this kind or request ? Are using NSURLConnection of AFNetworking ?

Comment: http://jayprakashdubey.blogspot.in/2014/09/invoke-soap-web-service.html

Answer (score 0):

Just starting into this now. I found this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/urlloadingsystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1

stating this: Only HTTP and HTTPS protocols are supported (no custom protocols).

Which leaves me more than a little bit concerned.

Update: I'm receiving SOAP responses - even though it is technically a custom protocol.